# ruby thread vs thread pool .. approved solution vs speed

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

I have code that need to be run many times in parallel.
I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682634/how-to-wait-for-thread-notification-instead-of-joining-all-the-threads) a code that wakeup the main thread, joining the childs, when one thread found valid solution :

```
valid_answer = nil
threads = []

1500.times do
  threads << Thread.new do 
    Thread.current[:output] = do_some_stuff
    valid_answer ||= Thread.current[:output] and Thread.main.wakeup if valid_answer != nil
  end
end

sleep
threads.each { |t| t.kill if t.alive? }
puts valid_answer
```

this solution is the good but very slow.
When I use ThreadPool, there is a visible gain in term of speed but I don't find how to stop the pool at the first thread valid answer

```
require 'thread/pool'

pool = Thread.pool(1500)
1500.times {
  pool.process {
    sleep 2
    do_some_stuff

              }
}
pool.shutdown
```

any advice please ?

Comment: Isn't it working the same way (by using `Thread.main.wakeup`)?

Comment: Hi, I'll try tonight and will update

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a global flag that is periodically checked by do_some_stuff.  If do_some_stuff sees the flag set, it should clean up (if needed) and return as soon as possible.  Set the flag as soon as a valid answer is found.

Threads should cooperate.  It's almost always better to *ask* a thread to do something instead of *forcing* it to do something.